# I cannot save Httponly cookie with post request with NodeJs Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, setcookie

when i try to send request i can see 'set-cookie' in  header but it is not saving on browser but i have another page when i send 'get' request it is working well and saving

[cookie in response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IlW4.png)

Back-End code

```
  return{
        statusCode:200,
        headers:{
         'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'https://front-end domain',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Set-Cookie':"token=" + token+";path=/; HttpOnly; Domain=apidomain; SameSite=Strict; secure; expires=Tue, 06 Sep 2023 22:10:32 GMT"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
```

Front-End Code

```
  const response = await fetch("https://api adres/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json",'x-api-key': 'AVlZ2gnoY99k9la40l5Ph1Mt5AdzLtqE4w5qLl48' },
      body: JSON.stringify({username,password,rememberme}),
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    if (response.status === 200) {
      console.log(json.token);
    } else {
        alert(json.message);
    }
```

i am trying to create login page with httponly cookie but i can not save on browser

Answer (score -1):

if you want to save cookie in the browser set HttpOnly = false.
the best solution is to keep HttpOnly = true and save the token in the context of the application to be able to use it in other requests.

[if HttpOnly = true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv87Z.png)

Comment: He ask how to save the tokwn on cookie with http only, you did not give an answer